# React Conditional Rendering Failing

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering

I'm working with a react component trying to do conditional rendering but i keep getting undefined for the header trying to display the name of the last position of the array

```
class Users extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        users: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({}))
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        users: []
    };
    renderContent() {

        const length = (this.props.users.length);
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12}>
                <Table responsive striped bordered>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>BirthDay</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.props.users.map(user => (
                            <tr key={user.name + user.surname + user.countries + user.birthday} className="table-vertical-middle ta-user-row">
                                <td className="ta-username">{user.name} {user.surname}</td>
                                <td className="ta-country">{user.countries}</td>
                                <td className="ta-birthday">{user.birthday}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Col>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <h2>{this.props.users[length].name} {this.props.users[length].surname}</h2>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Row>


        );
    }
```

Here I do the condition, do not render unless you have the data

```
render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            {this.props.users && this.renderContent()}
        </Grid>
    );
}
   }
```

Connection to redux

```
export default connect(
    state => ({users: state.user.users}),
)(Users);
```

Comment: Can you share your entire component?

Comment: I added the rest

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are accessing the users array at an undefined index. try the following.

```
<h2>{this.props.users[length - 1].name} {this.props.users[length - 1].surname}</h2>
```

Comment: I get undefined even if i use 0

Comment: Is there any users in the array? I assume not, is the users even an array or is it undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`this.props.users[length -1]`

That should work.